Nuxt App Error: Package import specifier "#internal/nitro/virtual/app-config" is not defined
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my Nuxt application locally after i install nuxt content module before it the project is woring normally . The app fails to start and throws the following error:
<[4:07:07 pm] ERROR [worker reload] [worker init] Package import specifier "#internal/nitro/virtual/app-config" is not defined in package C:\Users\Shobhit\Desktop\klimas\content01\net-ninja-portfolio\node_modules\nitropack\package.json imported from C:\Users\Shobhit\Desktop\klimas\content01\net-ninja-portfolio\node_modules\nitropack\dist\runtime\config.mjs>
Steps Taken to Resolve:
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json:
Deleted node_modules folder and package-lock.json file.
Ran npm install to reinstall dependencies.
Updated nitropack:
Checked package.json and ensured the latest version of nitropack.
Ran npm install nitropack@latest.
Checked Compatibility:
Ensured all dependencies are compatible with the current nitropack version.
Verified the Nuxt version.
Checked Configuration:
Verified nuxt.config.js for any misconfigurations related to nitropack.
Tried a Fresh Nuxt Project:
Created a new Nuxt project using npx create-nuxt-app new-nuxt-app.
Installed nitropack in the new project and ran it successfully.
Cleared npm Cache:
Ran npm cache clean --force.
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json again, followed by npm install.
Reinstalled Node.js:
Uninstalled Node.js completely.
Reinstalled Node.js version 18.27.
Reinstalled project dependencies with npm install.
Operating System: Windows
Steps Taken to Resolve:
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json:
Deleted node_modules folder and package-lock.json file.
Ran npm install to reinstall dependencies.
Updated nitropack:
Checked package.json and ensured the latest version of nitropack.
Ran npm install nitropack@latest.
Checked Compatibility:
Ensured all dependencies are compatible with the current nitropack version.
Verified the Nuxt version.
Checked Configuration:
Verified nuxt.config.js for any misconfigurations related to nitropack.
Tried a Fresh Nuxt Project:
Created a new Nuxt project using npx create-nuxt-app new-nuxt-app.
Installed nitropack in the new project and ran it successfully.
Cleared npm Cache:
Ran npm cache clean --force.
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json again, followed by npm install.
Reinstalled Node.js:
Uninstalled Node.js completely.
Reinstalled Node.js version 18.27.
Reinstalled project dependencies with npm install.
Operating System: Windows

I also had this when switching from Yarn to PNPM. Removing the node_modules folder and run pnpm i did the trick for me.

Something that fixed here is stop using pnpm. If I run pnpm install and later on I run the server I got this error, if I just run npm install and then npm run dev it runs smoothly. But it needs be run in a new repo in which pnpm was never used.
